# Remove newlines in Microsoft SQL over all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to replace all newlines in all the columns of a database before exporting it to a csv.

I can get it to work if I specify the columns, but I have over 200

Example that works for 1 column:

```
SELECT replace(
          replace([Incident_Number],char(10),' '),char(13),' ') AS [Incident_Number]
FROM [itsmwh].[dbo].[HELP_DESK];
```

How can I get this to work for all the columns in my table?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can write a script to generate a script for you.

I would do something like this......

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Sql =  STUFF((SELECT  ', replace(replace(' + QUOTENAME(C.name) 
                     +  ',char(10),'' ''),char(13),'' '') AS '+QUOTENAME(C.name) +' '
FROM sys.columns c 
inner join sys.tables  t ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
inner join sys.schemas s ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
Where t.name = 'TableName'  --<-- Table Name
 and  s.name = 'SchemaName'  --<-- Schema Name
FOR XML PATH('') , TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @Sql = 'SELECT ' + @Sql + ' FROM [itsmwh].[dbo].[HELP_DESK]; '

Exec sp_executesql @Sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one as well

```
DECLARE @tblName VARCHAR(20) = '[itsmwh].[dbo].[HELP_DESK]'
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns, 'REPLACE(REPLACE(') + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '], CHAR(10), '' ''), CHAR(13), '' ''), REPLACE(REPLACE('
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tblName

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + LEFT(STUFF(@columns, LEN(@columns), 1, ''), LEN(STUFF(@columns, LEN(@columns), 1, '')) - LEN(', REPLACE(REPLACE')) + ' FROM ' + @tblName
EXEC(@sql)
```